# Lisp interpreter quoting, in python

Tags: python, lisp, interpreter

I would like to write a lisp interpreter in python. It works with non-recursive  expressions. However, I find it confusing to quote in recursion.

A description of the following program:

1. The lisp code written in a string is parsed in the `parse()` function by replacing whitespace and parentheses with comma and brackets, and pass to the python's `eval()` function.
2. The dictionaries of symbols and syntax contain primitive procedures.
3. The evaluation works recursively, where syntax patterns has the ability to change the environmental dictionary. (`label` => extend the current dictionary,`lambda` => create a new dictionary). `quote` returns what is behind it directly. As for a procedure, it works by calling them after all its statements is evaluated.

That's it.

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import re

def parse(s):
    l = re.sub(r'\s+', ', ', (' '+s.lower()+' ').replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']'))[2:-2]
    return eval(re.sub(r'(?P<symbol>[\w#%\\/^*+_\|~<>?!:-]+)', lambda m : '"%s"' % m.group('symbol'), l))

def cons(a, d):
    if atom(d):
        return (a, d)
    return (lambda *args : list(args))(a, *d)

def car(s):
    return s[0]

def cdr(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return []
    return s[1:]

def atom(s):
    return not isinstance(s, list)

def eq(s, t):
    return s == t

def cond(l, d):
    for [p, e] in cdr(l):
        if eval_(p, d):
            return eval_(e, d)

class lambda_object:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, l, d):
        self.dic = d
        self.li = l[1]
        self.ex = l[2]
        lambda_object.count += 1
        self.serial = lambda_object.count

    def __call__(self, *args):
        for i in range(len(self.li)):
            self.dic[self.li[i]] = args[i]
        return eval_(self.ex, self.dic)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'COMPOND-PROCEDURE-#%d' % self.serial

    __repr__ = __str__

def label(l, d):
    d[l[1]] = eval_(l[2])

def quote(l, d):
    return l[1]

symbol_s = {'cons':cons, 'car':car, 'cdr':cdr, 'atom?':atom, 'eq?':eq, '#t':True, '#f':False}
syntax_s = {'cond':cond, 'lambda':lambda_object, 'quote':quote, 'label':label}


def eval_(l, s=symbol_s):
    print 'code =>', l
    if atom(l):
        return symbol_s[l]
    #if not atom(l[0]):
    #    l[0] = eval_(l[0])
    if l[0] in syntax_s:
        return syntax_s[l[0]](l, s)
    else:
```

---

### EDIT:

According to the answer, the following lines are incorrect:

```
        for i in range(len(l))[1:]:
            l[i] = eval_(l[i])
        print 'sval =>', l
        if isinstance(l[0], str):
            l[0] = s[l[0]]
        return l[0](*l[1:])
```

they should be:

```
        operator = eval_(l[0], s)
        operands = map(lambda e: eval_(e,s), l[1:])
        print 'sval =>', operator, '<<', operands
        return operator(*operands)
```

---

That's the program.

While running:

```
code = '''
(label ff
  (lambda (s)
    (cond
      ((atom? s) s)
      (#t (ff (car s))))))
'''
print eval_(parse(code))
print symbol_s

print eval_(parse("(ff (quote (((a b) c))))"))
```

It yields something sort of:

```
code => ['label', 'ff', ['lambda', ['s'], ['cond', [['atom?', 's'], 's'], ['#t', ['ff', ['car', 's']]]]]]
code => ['lambda', ['s'], ['cond', [['atom?', 's'], 's'], ['#t', ['ff', ['car', 's']]]]]
None
{'cons': <function cons at 0x10efcaf98>, 'ff': COMPOND-PROCEDURE-#1, 'eq?': <function eq at 0x10efcaf28>, 'car': <function car at 0x10efca978>, '#f': False, 'atom?': <function atom at 0x10efcad68>, 'cdr': <function cdr at 0x10efcab38>, '#t': True}
code => ['ff', ['quote', [[['a', 'b'], 'c']]]]
code => ['quote', [[['a', 'b'], 'c']]]
sval => ['ff', [[['a', 'b'], 'c']]]
code => ['cond', [['atom?', 's'], 's'], ['#t', ['ff', ['car', 's']]]]
code => ['atom?', 's']
code => s
sval => ['atom?', [[['a', 'b'], 'c']]]
code => #t
code => ['ff', ['car', 's']]
code => ['car', 's']
code => s
sval => ['car', [[['a', 'b'], 'c']]] 

;; from this line, the quotation disappeared

sval => ['ff', [['a', 'b'], 'c']]
code => ['cond', [[<function atom at 0x10efcad68>, [[['a', 'b'], 'c']]], 's'], ['#t', [COMPOND-PROCEDURE-#1, [['a', 'b'], 'c']]]]
code => [<function atom at 0x10efcad68>, [[['a', 'b'], 'c']]]
code => [[['a', 'b'], 'c']]
code => [['a', 'b'], 'c']
code => ['a', 'b']
code => b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "slisp.py", line 113, in <module>
    print eval_(parse("(ff (quote (((a b) c))))"))
...
  File "slisp.py", line 66, in eval_
    return symbol_s[l]
KeyError: 'b'
```

I understand that there is something wrong, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.
while evaluating `(ff (quote (((a b) c))))`, it is changed to `(ff ((a b) c))` in the next recursion without the quotes.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: While your interpreter _could_ work, I think it's a bit to confusing. You should have a look at an interpreter like [Peter Norvig's](http://norvig.com/lispy.html). You also may want to read a bit [more about quotes first](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Quoting.html).

Comment: Lisp expressions are described by context-free grammars, which regular expressions are not powerful enough to parse.

Comment: Well this is not a serious problem yet... It works in this program.

Comment: @ChristianDean I have read these two websites. However I still couldn't figure whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ff` is a procedure it evaluates it's arguments.. In the first case it has the argument `(quote (((a b) c)))` in it applies it:

```
code => ['ff', ['quote', [[['a', 'b'], 'c']]]]
code => ['quote', [[['a', 'b'], 'c']]]
sval => ['ff', [[['a', 'b'], 'c']]]
```

The second time around it has the argument `(car s)` where `s` is a bound variable.

```
code => ['ff', ['car', 's']] ;; unevaluated expression
code => ['car', 's']
code => s
sval => ['car', [[['a', 'b'], 'c']]] ;; what apply gets for car

;; from this line, the quotation disappeared
sval => ['ff', [['a', 'b'], 'c']] ;; what apply gets for ff
```

As far as I can see I cannot see any error here. It does exactly what it is supposed to do.

There is perhaps a bug somewhere else. When you look at the cond output from one to the other recursion:

```
code => ['cond', [['atom?', 's'], 's'], ['#t', ['ff', ['car', 's']]]]
code => ['cond', [[<function atom at 0x10efcad68>, [[['a', 'b'], 'c']]], 's'], ['#t', [COMPOND-PROCEDURE-#1, [['a', 'b'], 'c']]]]
```

These should have been identical except for the environment since its the same code. If you look at what you do in `eval_` I see you do :

```
`l[i] = eval_(l[i])`
```

This is bad since l contains your AST. The second you revisit this the evaluations will not be on the symbols of the code that were but the values you got the previous time around. You need to evaluate operator and operands to something else and then apply them.

I'm not a python programmer, but I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
operator = eval_(l[0], s)
operands = map(lambda e: eval_(e,s), l[1:])
return operator(*operands);
```

You do it several places though so everywhere you do `=` with code is probably a subject to change.

Comment: Thanks for reading my question. Yes, I meant, how not to change the AST? I thought for hours however I couldn't find a way not change it while keeping this program work.

Comment: In this line ['ff', [['a', 'b'], 'c']], [['a', 'b'], 'c'] is evaluated. I want to prevent it and I don't know how.

Comment: @virtualize Not really. `sval` comments show every argument that is to be applied and the arguments are not touched.

Comment: However, I would insist on my idea that the line is evaluated, for `code => [[['a', 'b'], 'c']]` tells the truth :)

Comment: @virtualize not.. you make a variable like `operator` not overwrite you code.. Never use l[0] but operator after that. You then check if operator is in syntax_s etc...